# Why event 'beforepaste' fires twice when user paste content into a contenteditable div AND right click it in IE (11)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Here's the code

```
var editable = document.getElementById("editable");
editable.addEventListener('beforepaste',function(e){
    alert('before paste');
});
editable.addEventListener('paste', function(){
  alert('paste');
});
```

When I paste something there, it fires event beforepaste once then the paste event and then again the beforepaste. And event when I right click it, the beforepaste event fires twice. This only occurs in IE (11), not in Chrome or neither Firefox. Is this a bug? If not, how to fix it?

Link to plnkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/9q9x54dWy0hoZs0rJ1i1/preview

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `alert` and instead using a `console.log`, have seen this fix doubles before.